# Error al ejecutar método DELETE en API REST Genexus 18

Tags: api, rest, delete, genexus18

Estoy haciendo un CRUD en Genexus 18 (Versión: 18.0.179127 U7). Todos los métodos funcionan bien (GET, POST, PUT) salvo el DELETE. Este es el código de mi objeto API:

```
Attractions {

  [RestMethod(DELETE)]
  [Description("Eliminar atracción")]
  Delete(in:&AttractionId, out:&Messages)
  => Servicios.DeleteAttraction(in: &AttractionId, out: &Messages);
  
}
```

Y este es el procedimiento DeleteAttraction:

```
//Pestaña Rules: Parm(in: &AttractionId, out: &Messages);

&Attraction.Load(&AttractionId)
&Attraction.Delete()

If &Attraction.Success()
    commit
else
    rollback
endif

&Messages = &Attraction.GetMessages()
```

Al correr el **test unitario** del procedimiento, el borrado se ejecuta correctamente, por lo que descarto que haya algún error en el procedimiento. Pero si lo ejecuto con Postman o con SoapUI, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
{
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Id": "CandidateKeyNotFound",
            "Type": 1,
            "Description": "Please 'Get' data before trying to update it."
        }
    ]
}
```

Ya seguí los pasos que se detallan acá: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?50053,API+object+Considerations.

Estoy usando .NET Framework como entorno, con SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS2012), todo local.

Sospecho que debe de ser algún tema de permisos, pero por lo que veo mi usuario está habilitado para Modificar. Igualmente me gustaría saber cómo estar seguro de eso y qué otros pasos puedo seguir para intentar solucionar el problema.